Accessing a dynamic Google Earth URL via JavaScript with some certain coordinates, but it actually sends me to the previous saved location
I'm trying to access a dynamic Google Earth URL via JavaScript which works great, but I have only one problem. By doing so, after a while, because of the cookies that are saved on that page it seems that it won't get me to where it is supposed to get me, and it sends me to the previous saved location from cookies, because after I clear the cookies from Google Earth manually, it works. I don't want to clear them manually every time, because this is for an app with users. I want to solve this problem from JavaScript code.
Code snippet:
window.open(`https://earth.google.com/web/search/${coords[0]},+${coords[1]}/@${coords[0]},${coords[1]},196.55454222a,112.74878798d,35y,0h,0t,0r`, '_blank');


surely there's more to it than one line of code

"I want to solve this problem from JavaScript code." - you can't do anything about cookies Google might set under their domain(s), with JavaScript from your end.
